# Is there a graphical menu editor for LXQT or LXDE?

Tags: lxde, lxqt, menu-editor

I have been trying out LXQT after some Plasma 5 upgrades went sour on me and there seems to be no way to edit the graphical menu via the customary right-click on the start menu. Searching the web gives the impression that there isn't a built-in one.

Am I missing some tool or is there no menu editor actually built into LXQT/LXDE?

Comment: First hit on DuckDuckGo: https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu

Comment: @Peschke that seems like a reasonable-enough answer to me; would you like to convert your comment into an Answer?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [LXDE Wiki:](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu)

> The Menu-plugin is part of the LXPanel and follows the standards of freedesktop.org. **The Menu-plugin does not provide graphical editing of the menu itself therefore external tools should be used.**
>
> - The [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) can be used now to edit menu - since version 1.2.0 all the menu editing operations are supported in Applications folder, except for separators (being a file manager, PCManFM shows only folders and applications, ignoring any separators).
> - The [Alacarte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alacarte) is well known menu editor from GNOME project written in Python.
> - One can download and compile [LXMED](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxmed/), a menu editor for LXDE written in Java, which requires GKSU.